# How to force conformance of associatedtype

Tags: swift

I have a question about using associatedtype in a generic protocol. In the following example, I'm trying to create a generic persister with an associated type **Item** conform to **NSCoding**

```
protocol Persister {
    
    associatedtype Item : AnyObject, NSCoding
    
    var itemCount: Int {get set}
    
    mutating func removeValue(at key: String?)
    
    mutating func store(_ item: Item?, for key: String?)
    
    subscript(index: String) -> Item? {get set}
    
}


extension Persister {
    mutating func store(_ item: Item?, for transactionIdentifier: String?) {
        if let id = transactionIdentifier {
            self[id] = item
        }
    }
    
    mutating func removeValue(at key: String?){
        store(nil, for: key)
    }
}


protocol PendingCreationPersister:  Persister where Item : PendingCreation{}
```

or

```
extension PendingCreationPersister where Item : PendingCreation{}
```

using this generic persister, as property in a class, like:

```
var persistentList : PendingCreationPersister
```

will rise the error: *"Protocol 'PendingCreationPersister' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"* even though the type of associatedtype is specified in the child protocol **PendingCreationPersister**. How could I prevent this issue?

Comment: create a generic structure using your protocol as the constrain for the generic type. Use the generic type for your property instead of the protocol

Comment: class Test {

}

extension Test: PendingCreationPersister {
typealias Item = PendingCreation

// implement the necessary propertires of the protocol in the extension of Test class 
}